# How to design independent header and footer page

Tags: php, web, ini

I am new in web designing.my website is based on articles.I want that it must be searchiable by search engine and each page open with header and footer of site with it direct link example let I have article on WiFi_connectivity.html in directory root/article than link is 
Mysite.com/article/WiFi_connectivity.html;

But point is that I don't want add  header and footer in each page and page should have its original link for that article for bookmark or else

Comment: So you have some kind of header and footer that you want to be included on each page?

Answer (score 0):

You would just include the header and footer files like so:

```
<?php
//set variables for your head tags here. title, keywords etc....
include('header.php');
//Your content goes here
include('footer.php');
?>
```

Your header.php file would look something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
<meta keywords="<?php echo $keywords; ?>"
</head>
//the rest of your header.php code here
```

To keep it SE friendly do all of your code above the first include so you can add proper title, meta tags, etc to the header file. Then just name the page what ever relevant name you like and it will retain the dynamic title for bookmarks.

This is an overly simple version but it is just to give you a rough idea of where to start.

Comment: right and I also add js file even in static page but I don't want to add anything in article page.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. There are a few different ways of doing it but either way at some point you are going to have to use an include on the article pg to include the header and footer files unless you use javascript to inject them. But you did tag this as php, and javascript just isn't my thing... LOL ;)

Comment: It sounds like you are going to need ajax then. I don't write that either so this is just a rough guess but you would write your header and footer as one file then add your links to your articles. When the user clicks on that link ajax would load the article into the content area of your page.

Comment: can you hint me some other way from server side;I hope you must replay

Comment: There is no other way that I know of, either you use include somewhere or you use a server side script.